# Beale's method of quadratic programming

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I was looking for a working algorithm of Beale's method to solve the usual quadratic programming problems alongwith a supporting example to explain the method. 
I have been looking for it for a while but it doesn't seem to help. 
Any reference or link would be really helpful.